# Xcode 8.2.1 install xvim plugin not working?

Tags: xcode, xvim

This is the first time I tried to use xvim.

I downloaded xvim from github, then follow the instuctions in [README](https://github.com/XVimProject/XVim/blob/master/INSTALL_Xcode8.md).

1. Recodesign Xcode
2. then `sudo make`

`build succeeded.`

But when I opened xcode, didn't see any changes. I dont know whether I install xvim correctly, or just xvim did'nt start.

Where should I open xvim? Please give me a hint.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I fixed this problem myself.

I believe the problem is that others could simply run `make`,

but I had to run `sudo make` to successfully built Xvim, which caused `XVim.xcplugin` to install in 
`/private/var/root/Library/ApplicationSupport/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins`

While you open Xcode as a normal user, Xcode needs plugins from

`~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins`

so I copied `XVim.xcplugin` to the right place ,then problem solved...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (though it showed after xcode update). To fix it I had to re-codesign Xcode.

Instructions:

https://github.com/XVimProject/XVim2/blob/master/SIGNING_Xcode.md

After that I did make and XVim was working